# pick value from listbox and use in sql query as column name.query dynamically pick column name from variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables, select

I have VB.net app that when run you select from listbox values that should then be used in select query.Then click save command button.
see vb code snippet below

```
transport = lsttrans.SelectedItem
    leave = lstleave.SelectedItem
```

then query like below.Note transport and leave are dummy columns not on existing employee table.

```
select employeeid,'' as transport_allowance,'' as leave from employees
```

i wish to somehow create new query to be something close to the below using my selected values in listbox.

```
select employeeid,transport,leave from employees
```

Comment: To do that you would need to use dynamic SQL. Please read up on that.

Comment: Thanks let me have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **String.Format()**.
Here is the example assuming transport and leave variables are already declared:

```
Dim myQueryTemplate As String = "SELECT employeeid, {0}, {1} FROM employees"
Dim myFinalQuery as String = String.Format(myQueryTemplate, transport, leave)
```

If you will debug that, the value of myFinalQuery will be:

```
"SELECT employeeid, transport, leave FROM employees"
```

Add more if needed. From my given example, the next parameter will be {2} and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know how to retrieve data from a database in VB.NET?  If not then you should read up on ADO.NET.

Assuming that you know how ADO.NET works, your SQL is simply a `String`, so you can build it up from parts the same way you can any other `String`.  In this case, I would suggest calling the `String.Format` method to insert the column names into a query template.

Comment: yes I do thanks.dint know how to use the string.format feature though but now I do